# Invalid command line error with STM32F7 on Eclipse

Tags: stm32

I'm using Eclipse under Ubuntu  to work on an STM32F7 DISCOVERY I have set the system to flash my blinky project to the Discovery. After building the project I go to Run-> External Tools and hit Run to down load the code to flash but I get the following message on the Console window:

```
invalid command line
stlinkv1 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] [--reset] {read|write} /dev/sgX path addr <size>
stlinkv1 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] /dev/sgX erase
stlinkv2 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] [--reset] {read|write} path addr <size>
stlinkv2 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] erase
                   use hex format for addr and <size>
```

The External Tool Configurations I'm using is as follows:

```
Main-> Location /usr/local/bin/st-flash Main -> Working Directory ${project_loc}/Release Main -> Arguments:write${project_name}.bin 0x8000000
```

Comment: Will adding space between write and '${project_name}.bin in Arguments: section help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not give the path for the serial port. The output of the command line shows the syntax.